# How should one deal with code asking "Is this correct?" when it is in fact correct?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I'm wondering what a good guideline is when dealing with questions asking (primarily or completely) about correctness. Generally this is not what Code Review is about. However, when the code is actually correct and there are likely other things about it that could be reviewed, how should we proceed?

A (now-deleted) example is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/linear-search-java). This asks almost exclusively for correctness (which is easily verified). This is somewhat against the FAQ (as per *5. To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?*), although it could be argued that since it is correct, it's valid by this criterion.

What should be done with questions like this? Leave it be and give an actual "code review" even if isn't what was asked for, or close the question as *off topic*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my view, on Code Review you don't have to give the OP what they wanted. The whole point is to get feedback on your code. That feedback can be about anything. A lot of the time the correct feedback is that you should have done something completely different. So I don't think you need to feel restricted by what the OP was interested in.

Asking if your code is correct is on-topic. What we want to disallow is code that is known to be incorrect. We aren't a debugging service or how do I write this service. If you think your code is correct, but you'd like more eyeballs that's on topic here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.